# How can i update export path for VsCode "maven install" in MacOS?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, vscode-extensions

I'm using default VsCode Java Spring profile to create my multi-module application.

But when i run Maven install (following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72598461/16744957) it exports my .jar files in this path: ~/.m2/repository/com/myAppParent/myAppModule/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/myAppModule-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Anyone knows how can i set it to export in my project folder? Like java build does with ${workspaceFolder}/${workspaceFolderBasename}.jar

I've already tried to check "Maven For Java" extension settings, but haven't found anything...

Comment: You are looking for `mvn package`. `mvn install` installs the jar to your local repository (the `.m2` directory)

Comment: You seem to be confusing Maven install goal with the output folders of the build.

Comment: thanks @ChristopherSchneider and @aled!! I did have confused the objectives of package and install, now i've got wat i wanted!!